# react-native-device-detection not working with Nexus 7

Tags: mobile, react-native, width, tablet, device-detection

I had created an imageGallery application built over React-Native.
The basic requirement is

- Mobile View shows 3 images per row.
- Tablet View shows 5 images per row.

Device detection is done using [react-native-device-detection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-detection)

The number of images per row is limited using `Dimensions` object.

```
const Device = require('react-native-device-detection');
 if(Device.isTablet) {
 Object.assign(styles, {
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 5 - 10 ,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 5 - 10,
  }
 });
}
if(Device.isPhone) {
 Object.assign(styles, {
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3 - 10 ,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3 - 10,
  }
 });
}
```

This works fine in mobile and also in the simulator (Nexus 7). 
Checked with https://material.io/devices/. Nexus 7 comes under Tablet.
**Nexus 7 Emulator Screenshot**

[image: Nexus 7 Emulator Screenshot]

**Nexus 7 Device Screenshot**

[image: Nexus 7 Device Screenshot]
But in the device (Nexus 7) it shows 3 images per row.(Mobile behavior).

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I think the algorithm works based on the dpi of each devices. You can see the category on which your device belongs (density query vech row fix chyy, appo correct akum) https://material.io/devices/

Comment: Checked with https://material.io/devices/. Nexus 7 comes under Tablet.

Comment: check with density, xhdpi, hdpi like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nexus 7** is actually a mini [**tablet**](https://www.asus.com/in/Tablets/Nexus_7/) as per manufacturer. **react-native-device-detection** identifies the device on the basis of their height/width and pixelDensity like [this](https://github.com/m0ngr31/react-native-device-detection/blob/master/index.js#L21).

```
  isPhoneOrTablet() {
    if(this.pixelDensity < 2 && (this.adjustedWidth >= 1000 || this.adjustedHeight >= 1000)) {
      this.isTablet = true;
      this.isPhone = false;
    } else if(this.pixelDensity === 2 && (this.adjustedWidth >= 1920 || this.adjustedHeight >= 1920)) {
      this.isTablet = true;
      this.isPhone = false;
    } else {
      this.isTablet = false;
      this.isPhone = true;
    }
  }
```

There is a chance for wrong info if the device has unorthodox sizes, you can add your own custom calculations to make it more accurate.

Comment: Checked 
if (Device.pixelDensity === 1 && (Device.adjustedWidth == 600 || Device.adjustedHeight == 960)) {
            Device.isTablet = true;
            Device.isPhone = false;
        } 
inside the render function and it worked.